# Handle navigate from one icon to another icon.?

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-mobile

I am currently working on a standard windows mobile application .I am creating 3 columns and three rows. i want to show 9 icons on form. But which event is used to  handle navigate from one icon to another icon.?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what these rows and columns are in.  A custom control?  They're each seaprate controls?  Something else?  If they are each separate controls, then they will have a GotFocus and LostFocus event that you could use.